# What is the correct SQL syntax for this SQL statement

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I am using a Content Management system (DotNetNuke) that has a MS SQL backend.  The logfiles for the CMS system (not SQL Server) have become enormous so I wish to delete them.

I'm trying to execute a Truncate statement, but apparently the LogFile table is joined to three other tables.

A fellow in the community wrote a SQL script that takes all of this into consideration.  The instrtuction call for:

> Install by running as script from SQL item in Host menu inside DNN or
>   run in 
>        SQL Server Management Studio, after replacing placeholders {databaseOwner} and    {objectQualifier} by its proper values from
>   web.config file.

In the case of objectQualifier I checked web.config and it is:

```
objectQualifier=""
```

So my question in the following statement do I replace everything in the brackets AND delete the brackets as well with ""

Here is one of the many lines where I must replace this information:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'{databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}sys_currentDNNVersion]') AND Type = N'FN')
    DROP FUNCTION {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}sys_currentDNNVersion]
GO
```

I must do the same for {databaseOwner}

Comment: you sure you need to be dropping functions to truncate a table?.. either way you just need to get rid of `{databaseOwner}` and `{objectQualifier}` ,brackets and all, and just end up with something like `DROP FUNCTION [sys_currentDNNVersion]`

Comment: Ha!  That worked like a charm.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are referring to the EventLog.  In recent versions of DNN it has been organized into 3 tables, not the single table of prior versions.

Look here: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155180/howto-truncate-your-eventlog-in-dnn-740

You can also configure the Event Log so that you don't save everything.

If you are referring to other tables, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of Joe Craig. Before DNN 7.4 you could do this

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sitelog;
TRUNCATE TABLE schedulehistory;
TRUNCATE TABLE eventlog;
```

However they added 2 more columns to the EventLog with Foreign Keys so you cannot truncate it anymore.

[Download a script here](https://dnnscript.codeplex.com/releases/view/612643) (not mine). It will remove the constraints, truncate the tables and re-add the constraints again.